# Symfony3 and .gitignore

Tags: gitignore, symfony

I've just tried cloning a Symfony3 project from github and realised it doesn't include `/bin/` (as this was not required in Symfony2).

I have now updated my `.gitignore` to take out the `/bin/` and `/build/` directories to avoid this happening in future. Are there any other modifications that I'm missing that we should be making to a 'standard' Symfony3 `.gitignore` file?

My current content is as follows now:

```
/app/config/parameters.yml
/composer.phar
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
/var/
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
/phpunit.xml
```

Removed entries:

```
/bin/
/build/
```

Comment: Technically you are not cloning, you are using the Symfony installer.  Big difference.  In any event, self-update the installer and start over again.  An earlier version was loading the wrong stuff including an incorrect .gitignore.

Comment: Hi @Cerad, I did a `git clone <github repository>` to clone it locally and then did `composer install`

Comment: I don't think that there is a general answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a file that i used in a project from which i pulled in differents computers and untill now no problems, just pull and composer commands etc.
Hope it helps [i know is not perfect, any improves suggested are welcome]

```
/app/config/parameters.yml<br>
/build/<br>
/phpunit.xml<br>
/var/*<br>
!/var/cache<br>
/var/cache/*<br>
!var/cache/.gitkeep<br>
!/var/logs<br>
/var/logs/*<br>
!var/logs/.gitkeep<br>
!/var/sessions<br>
/var/sessions/*<br>
!var/sessions/.gitkeep<br>
!var/SymfonyRequirements.php<br>
/vendor/<br>
/web/bundles/<br>
```

Comment: That looks good thanks - in the one I've been trying I'm also including the following (any thoughts to include/exclude would be appreciated!): `/composer.phar`, `web/media/cache/` `/web/uploads/`

Comment: I think they are ok, in my case i dont have a composer.phar because i have it installed globally, about the /web/uploads depends on your project, may be you need them for someone to reproduce the posts or whatever the files where uploaded for.